# Creating folders in Outlook 2010

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2010

I have a folder containing many subfolders on my desktop that I need to recreate in outlook 2010. The folders are empty and I have it as a template. There is something like 400 folders so I am trying to avoid manually creating every one of them in outlook.

The issue I have is that these folders aren't being put under my inbox, they are going to be created under a common mailbox accessible by my coworkers. We are using this for archiving purposes. Most of the codes I have found are for creating folders under your inbox.

How would I go about recreating the directory under this public mailbox? I have very little experience in VBA programming. I also have all the folder names in excel if that makes it any easier to accomplish this.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I'd suggest starting from the [Getting Started with VBA in Outlook 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814736%28v=office.14%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) article in MSDN to learn the basics. From the Outlook object model there is no difference where the folder is located. The [Add](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff862204(v=office.15).aspx) method of the Folders class creates a new folder in the Folders collection.

You may use the [Stores](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff864790(v=office.15).aspx) property of the Namespace class which returns a Stores collection object that represents all the Store objects in the current profile. Also the [GetSharedDefaultFolder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869575(v=office.15).aspx) method of the Namespace class returns a Folder object that represents the specified default folder for the specified user.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to find what I was looking for in terms of referencing our public inbox and was able to figure out the rest from there.